# Trigger different events in JQuery based on if condition in html in Flask

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have developed a Flask website, which I need to trigger different alert messages depending on customers' salary after clicking on a button. I am doing the if statement inside the HTML using the Jinja2 template and according to condition triggers the id and then use this id to trigger an event using JQuery. I believe I am doing something wrong since nothing is happening after I click on the button.

Following is part of my code:

```
    <div>   
        {% if ((current_user.salary)>=2000 and (current_user.salary) <=5000)  %}
            <div id="msg0"></div>
        {% endif %}

        {% if ((current_user.salary)>=1000 and (current_user.GPA) <2000)  %}
            <div id="msg1"></div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

**JQuery** Code:

```
  $( document ).ready(function(){
      $("#second").unbind('click').bind( 'click', function() {
    $('#msg0').alert("Your salary is above 2000");
    $('#msg1').alert("You salary is less than 2000");
        });
});
```

I did not include the code for designing the button since it is irrelevant I can click on the button. However, I do not think what I am doing with `  is correct. Maybe my JQuery code is not correct.

I would appreciate it if anyone can help me.`

Comment: I want based on the if condition when I click on the button alert message, is triggered. For example if the salary is greater than 2000 I want to use the JQuery to trigger the alert. Since Jquery accepts the id or class and I did not know any other ways to incorporate id or class after if statement I used the div.

Comment: I see then how can you trigger a message on the screen according to this if statement.

Comment: I believe I can use $('msg0').text('   ') however I still do not see anything on the screen. I suspect the div element is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following code.

```
$(function(){
  $("#second").off('click').click(function() {
    if($("#msg0").length){
      alert("Your salary is above 2000");
    }
    if($("#msg1").length){
      alert("You salary is less than 2000");
    }
  }
});
```

You need to check which of these elements exist in the DOM. To do this, we can check if the jQuery Object has `length` of `1` or higher.